# Echoing table info without showing database information CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a function in CodeIgniter so I can print database information from 2 different tables and show it on my view page with an array.  Now the problem that I have when printing it is that it shows all the information including the row names etc..

It shows it like this on my view page:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 6 [email] => jeremy2@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [product_id] => 73 [category_id] => 3 [product_naam] => Tennisracket ) ) jeremy2@gmail.com Jeremy Tennisracket
```

And I only want it to echo the names like this:

```
**jeremy2@gmail.com Jeremy Tennisracket**
```

My view page:

```
<?php print_r($userdetail_list); 
        foreach($userdetail_list as $row)
                        {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['voornaam'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['product_naam'];?></td>
                         </tr>
       <?php } ?>
```

My controller function:

```
   public function details($product_id)
 {
  //load the Product_model
  $this->load->model('Product_model');

  //call function getdata in de Product_model
  $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

  //get product details
  $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);

  //laad view
  $data['main_content'] = 'details';
  $this->load->view('details',$data);
 }
```

My model function:

```
 public function getdata()
{
    $this->db->select('users.user_id,users.email,users.voornaam,products.product_id,products.category_id,products.product_naam');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
       return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should remove `print_r($userdetail_list); ` in your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a just simple silly mistake that you are printing whole array `print_r($userdetail_list);` just remove that part.